# how to do subplot histogram with different bins pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

```
x=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(400)) 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True, tight_layout=True, figsize=(10,5)); 
for idx in range(3):
    axs[idx].hist(x, bins=20)
    axs[idx].hist(x, bins=40)
    axs[idx].hist(x, bins=60)  
    axs[idx].hist(x, bins=100)
```

when i run the code above; i recieve this error

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'hist';

could you solve this issue please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `axs` is:

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fb9261a4a10>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fb9260fc510>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fb926130b10>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fb9260f1190>]],
      dtype=object)
```

So you want something like this:

```
x=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(400)) 

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharey=True, tight_layout=True, figsize=(10,5));     
axs[0, 0].hist(x, bins=20)
axs[0, 1].hist(x, bins=40)
axs[1, 0].hist(x, bins=60)
axs[1, 1].hist(x, bins=100)
```

Or you can use a for-loop like this:

```
b = [20, 40, 60, 100]
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.flatten()):
    ax.hist(x, bins=b[i])
```